# The following code returns error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, selection, worksheet

I am trying to use the name of the sheet on the code to select a Range. I have 37 sheets, and I don't want to write the code 37 times.

```
Sub relatorio()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, GI As Integer, J As Integer
    J = 0
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        J = J + 1
        If ws.Name = "Brasil" Then
            i = (8 * 0) + 4 And GI = (13 * 0) + 271
        End If
        If ws.Name <> "Dados" Then

            'the error occur in the next line.
            Worksheets(ws.Name).Shapes.Range(Array("TRI")).Select
            Selection.Formula = "=Dados!a2"
            Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
            Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 9

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheets(ws.Name).` can be replaced with `ws.`.
leaving you with:

```
ws.Shapes.Range(Array("TRI")).Select
```

Do you have a shape named "TRI" on the worksheet that it is erroring out on, or is the sheet itself hidden?

to avoid errors with sheets being hidden, and to avoid having to select each shape, I would suggest this:

```
with ws.Shapes.Range(Array("TRI")).Select
    .Formula = "=Dados!a2"
    .ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 9
end with
```

Comment: Yes the shape is named TRI

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on in your ode.

First off, the line:

```
i = (8 * 0) + 4 And GI = (13 * 0) + 271
```

... most likely is not doing what you intended. It works as an orphaned boolean criteria as it is now. Better leave it on two lines if you are trying to assign values to `i` and `GI`.

```
i = (8 * 0) + 4
GI = (13 * 0) + 271
```

Next thing would be your use of `ws`. Once you have this assigned to a [Worksheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224506(v=office.11).aspx) from the [Worksheets collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224508(v=office.11).aspx) through the [For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) you can use it directly. You don't need to use its name as a reference point.

```
Sub relatorio()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, GI As Integer, J As Integer
    J = 0
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        with ws
            J = J + 1
            If .Name = "Brasil" Then
                i = (8 * 0) + 4        'not at all clear what you are trying to do here
                GI = (13 * 0) + 271    'not at all clear what you are trying to do here
            End If
            If .Name <> "Dados" Then

                'the error occur in the next line.
                'the recorded code for selecting a shape object goes overboard; this is all you should require
                with .Shapes("TRI")
                    .Formula = "=Dados!a2"
                    .ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
                    .ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 9
                end with
            End If
        end with
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. How to make the formula change in each ws.

Comment: J = 0
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        with ws
            J = J + 1
            If .Name = "Brasil" Then
                i = (8 * 0) + 4
                GI = (13 * 0) + 271
            End If
            If .Name <> "Dados" Then
                with .Shapes("TRI")
                    .Formula = "=Dados!a(i)" 'I want the i to change in each ws 
                    .ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
                    .ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 9